# Problem in taking multiple inputs in 2d vector

Tags: c++

The following is the code for taking input from the keyboard in the form of a 3x3 2d integer vector, for n number of times(n also input from the keyboard). I wish the code to store a new vector after each iteration, which goes on n times, but it only stores the first input. to verify this, i printed the element at the position (2,1) of the vector after each iteration. I expect it to print the element from the new vector i enter but it always prints the element from the first vector only.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> test_case{};

    int n;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i{}; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            vector<int> line{};
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                int entry;
                cin >> entry;
                line.push_back(entry);
            }

            test_case.push_back(line);

        }
        cout << "\n" << test_case.at(2).at(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the following input:

```
4

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

4 5 8
7 3 2 
1 6 9 

1 4 7 
2 5 8
3 6 9

7 5 3
6 9 8
4 1 2
```

The output given is:

```
8
8
8
8
```

How do i rectify this problem??

Comment: The way you read in your matrices, you have one matrix with 3 columns and 3·n rows. If you want a vector of n 3×3 matrices, you must nest the vectors deeper. (But given that all your matrices are 3×3, you probably shouldn't use a `std::vector` for them)

Comment: You shouldn´t use `i` as counter for all three of your nested loops. The increments may interfere with each other.

Comment: @MOehm Should i try using arrays then?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio No it won't br a problem here because i does not appear in the statements within the for blocks, though i understand the reasoning and i actually use different letters mostly.

Comment: If all your matrices are going to be 3×3, I think using an `int m[3][3]` is clearer, yes. A `std::vector<int>` is useful if you want to hold a variable number of `int`s, but that's not the case with your matrices.

Comment: right. i'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read in one long vector of 3 columns and 3 × *n* rows, so the entry at (2, 1) will always refer to the first matrix. If you want to represent each matrix as separate, you should make your `vector` nest three levels deep: matrix, row and cell:

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> test_case{};
    int n;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i; i < n; ++i) {
        vector<vector<int>> matrix{};

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            vector<int> line{};

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                int entry;

                cin >> entry;
                line.push_back(entry);
            }

            matrix.push_back(line);

        }

        test_case.push_back(matrix);

        cout << "\n" << matrix.at(2).at(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But that's a bit of an overkill in my opinion. A `std::vector` is useful if you need an array of varying size. If you have 3 &times 3 matrices throughout, it might be betterto use a plain old 3 by 3 array and perhaps make them a type, so that you can easily stuff it into a `vector` of matrices. A simple way to do that is to use a `struct`:

```
struct matrix {
    int a[3][3];
};

int main()
{
    vector<matrix> test_case{};
    int n;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i; i < n; ++i) {
        matrix m;

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
                cin >> m.a[j][k];
            }
        }

        test_case.push_back(m);

        cout << "\n" << m.a[2][1];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That's rather raw and not very C++'ish, but you can always write a full-fledged `matrix` class if you like.